# Academic Puzzle : Derive Proportions Without Self Join

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

We have data arriving in the following structure

```
entity_id   entity_value   category_id   category_weight   group_id   group_weight
    1            100            11               6            101          4
    1            100            11               6            102          3
    1            100            12               5            102          3
    1            100            12               5            103          2
    1            100            13               6            101          4
```

An entity can belong to any category and any group in any combination, there is no implicit relationship between category membership and group membership.

The data is redundant but consistent; if one row says category 11's weight is 6, all rows will say category 11's weight is 6.  The same applies to groups and their weights.

A row of data is uniquely identified by `{entity_id, category_id, group_id}`.

The aim is to apportion the entity's value across all the rows, based on the various weights.  First, apportioning by category, then apportioning by group.

**Step 1 : Apportion by Category**

> Entity 1 is a associated with 3 categories {11, 12, 13} with weights {6, 5, 4}
>
> > Assign 100 * (6 / (6+5+6)) to category 11   =>   35.29
> >     Assign 100 * (5 / (6+5+6)) to category 12   =>   29.41
> >     Assign 100 * (6 / (6+5+6)) to category 13   =>   35.29

**Step 2 : Apportion those results by Group**

> Entity1Category11 is associated with groups {101, 102} with weights {4, 3}
>
> > Assign 35.29 * (4 / (4+3)) to group 101   =>   20.17
> >     Assign 35.29 * (3 / (4+3)) to group 102   =>   15.12
>
> Entity1Category12 is associated with groups {102, 103} with weights {3, 2}
>
> > Assign 29.41 * (3 / (3+2)) to group 102   =>   17.65
> >     Assign 29.41 * (2 / (3+2)) to group 103   =>   11.76
>
> Entity1Category13 is associated with groups {101} with weights {4}
>
> > Assign 35.29 * (4 / ( 4 )) to group 103   =>   35.29

The second step I can do with window functions.  Nice and tidy, no self joins.

The first step, however, appears to need sub-queries and self join.

For example...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/be890/1

```
SELECT
  sample.entity_id,
  sample.category_id,
  sample.group_id,
  sample.entity_value   AS original_value,
  sample.entity_value
  * (sample.category_weight / entity.total_category_weight)
  * (sample.group_weight    / SUM(sample.group_weight) OVER (PARTITION BY sample.entity_id, sample.category_id))
    AS apportioned_value
FROM
(
  SELECT
    entity_id,
    SUM(category_weight)   AS total_category_weight
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      entity_id,
      category_id,
      MAX(category_weight)   AS category_weight
    FROM
      sample
    GROUP BY
      entity_id,
      category_id
  )
    entity_category
  GROUP BY
    entity_id
)
  entity
INNER JOIN
  sample
    ON sample.entity_id = entity.entity_id
```

Is there a tidier way, without the need for the self join?

Comment: Just by typing the question out it jogged enough brain cells to arrive at this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/be890/7

Comment: I got the feeling the original table is denormalised. Does `normalising+joining the parts` count as *self join*? [BTW please add the (candidate) keys for the table to your question]

Comment: @wildplasser : Yes, because the data is already in the described state.  Normalising into three tables, for example, would involve parsing the source table three times; once per output normalised table.  As such the joins of those three normalised tables are essentially joining three (refactored) instances of source table to it self...

Comment: What is the first step?  I'm not following what the question really asks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Question updated.  The SQL in the question and the SQL Fiddle I added in the comments may be used to elaborate further *(as they give the expected results)*

Comment: @MatBailie, you should post a self-answer. Dividing `Weight` by `COUNT` is a good method to deal with what is essentially duplicated rows. I don't think you can get any better than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  entity_id,
  category_id,
  group_id,
  entity_value   AS original_value,
  entity_value
  * (category_weight / SUM(scaled_cat_weight) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id             ))
  * (group_weight    / SUM(group_weight     ) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id, category_id))
    AS apportioned_value
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    category_weight / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id, category_id)   AS scaled_cat_weight
  FROM
    sample
)
  scaled
ORDER BY
  entity_id,
  category_id,
  group_id
```